# spring ldap security without xml

Tags: spring-security

This documentation explains how to configure Spring-Security LDAP:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#ldap

> ```
> 3.4.5. Spring Bean Configuration
>
> <bean id="contextSource"
>         class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
>   <constructor-arg value="ldap://monkeymachine:389/dc=springframework,dc=org"/>
>   <property name="userDn" value="cn=manager,dc=springframework,dc=org"/>
>   <property name="password" value="password"/>
> </bean>
>
> <bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
>     class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
>  <constructor-arg>
>    <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
>      <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
>      <property name="userDnPatterns">
>        <list><value>uid={0},ou=people</value></list>
>      </property>
>    </bean>
>  </constructor-arg>
>  <constructor-arg>
>    <bean
>      class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
>      <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
>      <constructor-arg value="ou=groups"/>
>      <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="ou"/>
>    </bean>
>  </constructor-arg>
> </bean>
> ```

how can we achieve this without xml?
Here we have a sample which uses a local ldif file:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/ldap-jc/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/config/SecurityConfig.java

I've modified SecurityConfig.java as follows:

```
    public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(ldap_url);
        contextSource.setUrl(ldap_user);
        contextSource.setPassword(ldap_password);

        DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator ldapAuthoritiesPopulator = new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(contextSource, "ou=groups");
        ldapAuthoritiesPopulator.setGroupRoleAttribute("ou");

        LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer = auth.ldapAuthentication();

        ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource(contextSource)
            .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapAuthoritiesPopulator);
    }
}
```

but when I login using the web form, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.<init>(Hashtable.java:296)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getAuthenticatedEnv(AbstractContextSource.java:499)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.doGetContext(AbstractContextSource.java:114)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getContext(AbstractContextSource.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator.bindWithDn(BindAuthenticator.java:112)
```

Is there a similar documentation to http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#ldap explaining how to achieve this without spring xml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call

```
contextSource.afterPropertiesSet()
```

if you are using the class outside an application context (see the source and Javadoc for Spring LDAP's [AbstractContextSource](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/AbstractContextSource.java) for more information). Either that or you can just make it an `@Bean` and Spring will call the method and initialize it for you.

Also

```
contextSource.setUrl(ldap_user);
```

doesn't look right. Shouldn't that be `setUserDn` ?

Comment: I have just finished to build an example of application (3 days of hard work). https://github.com/jvmvik/gs-securing-war